# iis and sql server error?

Tags: iis-6

i make asp website with Framework="4.0" and sql database using c#
i can browse it in vb 2010 without any errors
then 
i put it in iis6 with windows 7
now 
I can browse the site but I can connect with sql database 
it gives me

---

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to failure in retrieving the user's local application data path. Please make sure the user has a local user profile on the computer. The connection will be closed.

---

thank you

Comment: are u sure u are using iis6 on Win 7?

Comment: please add details on the sql version you are trying to use. Just add the appropriate tags (sql server 2008, sql express, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are facing this error with IIS on Win 7 when trying to use Sql Express, you can try resolving the error by changing the id under which App Pool is running. By default in newer versions of IIS, the Application Pool runs  as the "application pool identity". You can try switching to a domain a/c or Network Service.

If that doesn't resolve the issue, try following the steps from:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2002980